# query about how exactly interfaces work in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Consider the following code:

```
interface MotorInterface
{
 public function start();
}

class Car
{
  private $motor;

  public function __construct(MotorInterface $motor)
   {
    $this->motor = $motor;
   }

  public function start() {
    return $this->motor->fire();
  }
}
```

I'm sort of confused about how Interfaces work when injected as dependencies. As you may have noticed, I've passed `MotorInterface` interface as dependency in `Car` class. The interface specifies only one prototype. But now consider this:

```
class PetrolMotor implements MotorInterface
{
 public function start() {
    return 'starting';
 }
 public function fire() {
    return 'firing';
 }
}
```

And this..

```
$motor = new PetrolMotor();
$car = new Car($motor);

var_dump($car->start());
```

It works and displays `firing`. However, I've never prototyped the `fire()` method in `MotorInterface`. How did it work?

Comment: So, you don't prototype method `fire` but have it in `PetrolMotor`. Now remove `fire` method from `PetrolMotor` and get an exception.

Comment: but I injected the interface which has only one method(prototype), how come the `car` class was able to pick `fire()` which isn't even defined. how does this behaviour work

Comment: You injected __not__ interface, but an object of class which implements this interface. And class can have other methods except methods defined in interface.

Comment: so sorry for wasting your time, it is indeed a stupid question i shouldn't have asked in the first place.... i'm embarrassed

Comment: Keep in mind that your Interface is a kind of abstract structure that will be implemented by classes, In your use case, you don't inject the interface or a class that implements it, but a precise instance of that class. So you can call any method that exists in this instance.

Comment: i'm lucky i didn't get any downvotes

Comment: @keaton016 - I don't think there is such a thing as a "stupid question", only questions you don't know the answer to, to which end, despite this being a very broad question (and technically flaggable for that), that doesn't make it bad, quite the contrary IMO, I think this is a good question and with that said, enjoy a +1 on me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does not limit what methods you can call on an object.

Quoting the [PHP Manual on Type Declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration):

> Type declarations allow functions to require that parameters are of a certain type at call time.

You injected a `PetrolMotor` which is a `MotorInterface`. This will satisfy the type hint. And that's all the type hint does. It does not technically limit what methods you can call on the object afterwards in any way. Your `PetrolMotor` has the `fire()` method, so you can call it despite `fire()` not being available in the interface.

However, the type hint does impact introspection in most IDEs though, which will then complain about the method not being available in interface.

Answer (score 0):

Think of an interface as a job spec for a project, it's a list of things a piece of code must have in order to be able to "work" in it's most basic form

For example, for a user, there is 1 main thing you really need above all else; login, so, we can look at it as such;

```
<?php

interface iUser
{
    function login($uname, $pword);
}
```

This sets out the basic rule for what a user class MUST have, to which end, we can create the class implementing this;

```
class User implements iUser
{
    public function login($uname, $pword)
    {
        /* code to login */
    }
}
```

Now, this doesn't mean you might not want more functionality outside of your interface as it's not relevant there, but is in your class, for example, you could have a onLoginCreateSession as below...

```
class User implements iUser
{
    public function login($uname, $pword)
    {
        /* code to login */
        onLoginCreateSession($uname); // Call this here in the event of successful login
    }

    private function onLoginCreateSession($uname)
    {
        /* set session variables for login success */
    }
}
```

The main reasoning behind an interface, is to allow a base set of rules for classes that may be similar, but have a different work set to achieve something, for example;

```
<?php
interface iCRUD
{
    public function create (array $data);
    public function read($recordid);
    public function update(array $data);
    public function delete($recordid);
}
```

This is a simple inerface, with 4 function definitions, but when we implement it...

```
class User implements iCrud
{
    public function create (array $data)
    {
        // create to a user table using data
    }
    public function read($recordid)
    {
        // read from a user table using id
    }
    public function update(array $data)
    {
        // update user table based on data
    }
    public function delete($recordid)
    {
        // delete from user table using id
    }
}

class Documents implements iCRUD
{
    public function create (array $data)
    {
        // create to a documents table using data
    }
    public function read($recordid)
    {
        // read from a documents table using id
    }
    public function update(array $data)
    {
        // update documents table based on data
    }
    public function delete($recordid)
    {
        // delete from documents table using id
    }
}
```

You can see how even the same interface can be used for multiple solutions